# AccessViolationException [SL / SyncFusion]

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, access-violation, syncfusion

I am currently developing using Silverlight 4.0 and I've encountered this tricky exception:

**AccessViolationException was encountered**
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This occurs on a regular basis when I load the SyncFusion Spreadsheet Control onto the screen. During the loading, however, I am performing quite a number of tasks (such as inserting values into the spreadsheet, enabling its CalcEngine, highlighting rows, applying borders, etc.). I am thus unable to pinpoint where the exception is thrown.

I'm running out of clues as to how to debug this exception. After this exception is thrown, I cannot return to the program flow (Silverlight simply crashes and the debugger is switched off), so I am not sure how to find the root of the problem.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've seen the call stack, and it shows me that System.Windows.dll is encountering the AccessViolationException on the method `PeriodicallyCleanUpNativePeers()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Spreadsheet Ribbon in your application then you have to add the assembly Syncfusion.Theming.Office2010Blue.dll to your application. By default spreadsheet ribbon is loaded with the office 2010 blue style. If you are not added this Theming assembly to your application, then it will also throw the AccessViolationException while loading.

Regards,
Sivakumar